# Can not manipulate a argjson argument in jq

Tags: variables, jq

having a bigger problem that basically comes down to some difference between types of arguments.

These work:

```
$ echo '{ "options": [ { "a": "b" } ] }' | jq -c '.options += [ { "c": "d" } ] | .options'
[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}]
$
```

and

```
$ jq -c --null-input '{ "options": [ { "a": "b" } ] } | .options += [ { "c": "d" } ] | .options'
[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}]
$
```

and:

```
$ jq -c --null-input --argjson options '[ { "a": "b" } ]' '$options[0].a'
"b"
$
```

But this does not:

```
$ jq -c --null-input --argjson options '[ { "a": "b" } ]' '$options += [ { "c": "d" } ] | $options'
jq: error (at <unknown>): Invalid path expression with result [{"a":"b"}]
$
```

I need the argjson defined var to gather objects mutually overriding each other, traversing a recursive JSON structure as that is the only way I found that, across functions, should work(tm).

I'm totally aware that I'm doing something wrong, so the blame is all mine, but this costed me too much time already, so I will be eternally thankfull for some angel showing me the errors of my ways.

Comment: What is your desired output? If you want to combine those you'll just need `$options + [ { "c": "d" } ]`

Comment: Which is what I do, in the failing task with the  +=

Comment: Have a look at sections [Variable / Symbolic Binding Operator: `... as $identifier | ...`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#Variable%2FSymbolicBindingOperator%3A...as%24identifier%7C...) and [Assignment](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#Assignment) in the manual. In the latter one it reads: "Note that the LHS of assignment operators refers to a value in `.`. Thus `$var.foo = 1` won't work as expected"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left-hand side of an assignment operator must refers to a value inside of `.`.

Put differently, the error you are getting is the result of an attempt to change `$options` without using an variable assignment. A variable assignment is done using `... as $var | ...`.

As such, your code should be

```
( $options + [ { "c": "d" } ] ) as $options | $options
```

That said, there's no reason to change `$options` here. The following would do:

```
$options + [ { "c": "d" } ]
```

---

Let's look at it from a different angle.

You have the following:

```
{ "options": [ { "a": "b" } ] } | .options += [ { "c": "d" } ] | .options
```

But you want to use `$options` instead of hardcoding the options. We would then use

```
{ "options": $options } | .options += [ { "c": "d" } ] | .options
```

That's overly complicated, though. There's no need to construct an object to contain our options if we're only interested in the options. This simplifies to the following:

```
$options + [ { "c": "d" } ]
```

Similarly, your first snippet simplifies to

```
.options + [ { "c": "d" } ]
```